# Drive letter remains after unmounting ISO/VHD

Tags: windows-8.1, iso-image, vhd, drive-letter

My System specs

- Windows 8.1 Pro 32-bit
- 4GB RAM
- 1TB HDD

When I unmount an ISO file or a vhd file via the Eject command in the right-click menu the file (ISO, VHD) ejects, but the drive letter remains there until the system is restarted.

If I reopen the same, or any other, ISO or VHD file a new drive letter gets created for it, and the original drive letter remains.

How could I remove that drive letter assignment without restarting my PC?

Comment: Hi raj arona, and welcome to Super User and Stack Exchange. This looks like the beginnings of a question: you have stated your problem, but you have not stated what your specific question is. Could you [edit] your question to include *a specific question* that we can provide an answer for? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in Windows for volume management is `mountvol`. You should be able to use the /D option to remove the dangling mount points. For example, if you want to recover (delete and make available for another use) the drive letter F:, you would normally run (as Administrator) this command:

```
mountvol F: /D
```

I can't promise this will work for you, because I've never encountered the problem you describe. It may be that the "real" fix is just to upgrade or re-install Windows. I'm currently running Win10 x64 on this machine and have just confirmed that this doesn't happen here, but I don't remember seeing it from Win8.1 x64 either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of why this keeps happening, but this might be a good solution in the meantime. To change drive letters go to Computer Management and then in the list go to Disk Management. You will see each drive listed. Right click on the drive you want to change and choose "Change Driver Letter and Paths". In the pop up window click Change and then another pop up will appear and you can choose from the list which you want. You will get a warning, but usually it is fine to say ok. I have no issues, but make sure it is ok for you. So you always have the option to go into those settings and make changes. Hopefully this was helpful. See attached pic.[image]